# Differentiation of convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I have a question about the conditions for which the following identity is valid:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f*g)=\frac{df}{dx}*g$$
The wikipedia states that it is valid if, say, $f\in C^\infty_c$ and g is a tempered distribution.

Question: is this also valid if $f\in C^\infty_c$ and $g$ is not tempered, for example $e^x$?

(the wiki doesn't give any proof or reference and i haven't been able to find anything through search)

thanks

Comment: The usual proof is by differentiating under the integral sign. If $f$ is compactly supported, you should be able to justify the differentiation by using the dominated convergence theorem.